# NodeJs Implementation with CakePHP or CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cakephp, socket.io

I have a nodeJs simple chat application using socket.io

> index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        //io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

> chat.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#form').submit(function (e) {
              socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
              $('#m').val('');
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;

          });
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="#">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got the idea and this is working fine as a separate project.
Now i have created a CMS in php. In listing page each user record has a poll button under users module. I want to connect user to socket using nodeJs and emit a message on click of button. Is it possible? If possible please help me to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible if you have your socket/server.js on a different port number else then your main server (mostly `80`, `8080` (Tomcat Apache) or `443` (SSL). That's what I did, and then load the files on your page with PHP.

Comment: CMS link is [http://example.com/users] with port 443. For socket suppose i will use 3000 port and link becomes [http://example.com:3000/users] then i have to put call using second link? And how would i load files.?

Comment: Can you help me with some example?

Comment: Main site: example.com > add script on your index.php or something `var io = io.connect('http://192.0.0.0:3000', { rememberTransport: false, secure: true});` and don't forget to include the JS files too!

Comment: Now facing the error " Cannot GET /users ". @C0dekid.php can you please tell me whats wrong now

Comment: You need to add the route and also the origins in your server: `io.set('origins', 'domain here');` and copy this script: http://pastebin.com/SLjGbQiW. Place these all in your server.js or something similar, depends on what filename you using

Comment: Thanks buddy for your time. I'll look into this further.